# Using Javascript eval(): wondering about code security/vulnerabilities

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a list of elements in my page that I want to apply a jQuery sliding animation to. But, I'd like it so that the animations are chained in order, i.e., an element will start its animation only when the previous one's animation has finished.

The list's length is variable, and so I need to find a dynamic solution.
I came up with this:

```
function closeYear(year, speed, complete) {
  $(year).next().slideUp(speed, complete);
}

function closeYears(years, speed, complete) {
  if ($(years).length == 1) {
    closeYear($(years).first(), speed, complete);
  } else if ($(years).length > 1) {
    var codeStr = ""
    $(years).slice(0, $(years).length - 1).each(function(k) {
      codeStr = codeStr + "closeYear($(years)[" + k + "],'" + speed + "',";
    });
    codeStr = codeStr + "closeYear($(years).last(),'" + speed + "',complete)" + Array($(years).length).join(")") + ";";

    eval(codeStr);
  }
}
```

With the above code, I am able to accomplish what I want, including being able to specify the speed of the animations, as well as a `complete` function to be executed when everything has been processed, like so:

```
closeYears($(".year"), "slow", function() {console.log("done!");})
```

My question is regarding the use of the `eval()` function. And because I am not very savvy with regards to security issues, I am wondering if there is anything  to be worried about in my code, the way it is written, or if there is a better/safer/smarter way to do what I want...

Any comments?

Comment: Its safe, but very very slow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)

Comment: most of the times if you need to use eval() you are doing something wrong. And looking at your code, you really do not need to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need a pseudo recursive function:

```
function closeYears(years, speed, complete) {
  (function close(i){
     if(!years[i])  return complete();
     closeYear(years[i],speed,function(){
        close(i+1);        
      } );
 })(0);
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully. I had tried something similar before but I must have been doing something wrong somewhere. Thank you very much @Jonas w